# Delphi - Get last created folder name from a given path

Tags: delphi

Is there a function to get the last created folder from a given path?
I want to see the last created folder in order to check if my camera has taken photos today.
Another approach I was thinking was to get the system date and then start searching for a folder that contained the current date.However if the camera date is wrong then this approach wont work!
Thanks. Any other ideas?

ex:

```
if lastcreatedfolder(dir_path):='05012016' then 
showmessage('TODAY A FOLDER WAS CREATED') 
else 
showmessage('NO FOLDER WAS CREATED TODAY!');
```

Comment: There's no such function. You need to enumerate the directories, and find the latest one, according to whatever criteria you settle upon.

Comment: Thanks.So i guess i have to enumerate all folders, get their creation date, sort the dates and get the last one.

Comment: You don't need to sort. You just need to enumerate the folders, keeping a note of the latest folder that you come across. Sorting is O(n log n), finding the max value is O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi 2010 also has the `IOUtils.pas` unit.

Using this unit, the last created folder may be found as follows:

```
uses
  IOUtils, Types, DateUtils;

function FindLastCreatedDirectory(const APath: string): string;
var
  LastCreateTime : TDateTime;
  PathsInQuestion: TStringDynArray;
  n : Integer;
begin
  LastCreateTime := MinDateTime;
  Result := '';

  PathsInQuestion := TDirectory.GetDirectories(APath);
  for n := Low(PathsInQuestion) to High(PathsInQuestion) do
  begin
    if CompareDateTime(TDirectory.GetCreationTime(PathsInQuestion[n]), LastCreateTime) = GreaterThanValue then
    begin
      LastCreateTime := TDirectory.GetCreationTime(PathsInQuestion[n]);
      Result := PathsInQuestion[n];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this code. There is a problem however. The result is not accurate. For example i have 2 folders: 2015-12-28  created ‎December ‎29, ‎2015, ‏‎18:22:00(according to windows7 explorer) and  2015-12-29 created ‎December ‎29, ‎2015, ‏‎18:21:54. Your function shows me that the last created item was 2015-12-29.

Comment: @user2858981 yes you are right. I have modified it a bit with the CompareDateTime function, so it works - hopefully also on your side.

Comment: Thanks now it works fine! It also has the advantage that lists the subfolder of the given path.

Answer (score 2):

The last created directory in a given path can be found using the [System.SysUtils.FindFirst](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.FindFirst) function.

The `TimeStamp` field of the [`TSearchRec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.TSearchRec) record can be checked using the function's `var F` parameter in order to evaluate the timestamp of a file system element.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows;

function getLastCreatedDirectory(const APath: string): string;
var
  res: TSearchRec;
  lastCreatedFileTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result := '';
  FillChar(lastCreatedFileTime, SizeOf(TFileTime), 0);

  if FindFirst(APath, faDirectory, res) = 0 then begin
    try
      repeat
        if (res.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then
          Continue;

        if (res.Name = '.') or (res.Name = '..') then
          Continue;

        {if res.TimeStamp > lastCreatedTime then begin
          lastCreatedTime := res.TimeStamp;
          Result := ExtractFilePath(APath) + res.Name;
        end;}

        if CompareFileTime(res.FindData.ftCreationTime, lastCreatedFileTime) = 1 then begin
          lastCreatedFileTime := res.FindData.ftCreationTime;
          Result := ExtractFilePath(APath) + res.Name;
        end;

      until FindNext(res) <> 0;
    finally
      System.SysUtils.FindClose(res);
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  WriteLn(getLastCreatedDirectory('C:\Program Files (x86)\*'));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

---

**EDIT 2**
Since `res.TimeStamp` seems to give the last modified date and the `TSearchRec.Time` field has been deprecated, the folder's creation time can be obtained evaluating the `res.FindData.ftCreationTime` field of the `TSearchRec` record.

Comment: In delphi2010 I had to change "res.Timestamp" to "res.time" in order to compile. Also If I create a folder and place a file in it it will display this folder. If I delete the last created folder this function will not show the last created folder from the remaining folders.

Comment: mmm... res.time is deprecated in my XE7 sysutils unit. I'm going to edit the answer with the usage of the `GetFileAttributesEx` function which may suits better your needs

Comment: In order to force listing only directories I added // Only show directories
        if (res.attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory then begin". Thank you fantaghirocco. This is an excelent solution!

Comment: oops, I missed the doc where it says "*The Attr parameter specifies the special files to **include in addition** to all normal files.*". Answer edited according to your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

if folder created by yourself you can save that folder name on an array even if name is random character, but if folder created by program or etc,
you can go to folder

```
cd "path"
    exp: cd /home
```

and use 'bellow' command that sort by date created files and folders,

so if there is meny files use this:

```
    ls -lt | less
```

also 'head' command can be usefull for you i think